# Solving non-homogenous differential equation $\ddot{y}+\frac km\dot{y}=-g\hat{j}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve this non-homogeneous second-order linear ordinary differential equation $$\ddot{y}+\frac km\dot{y}=-g\hat{j}$$
> $\hat{j}$ is just unit vector in $y$ direction.

I found the solution to homogenous part $y_h(t)=c_1+c_2e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$. By variation of parameters assume $y_p(t)=c_1(t)+c_2(t)e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$. I calculated $\dot{y}_p=c_1'(t)+c_2'(t)e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}-\frac{k}{m}c_2(t)e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$ and $\ddot{y}_p(t)=c_1''(t)+c_2''(t)e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}-c_2'(t)\frac{k}{m}e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}-c_2''(t)\frac{k}{m}e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}+(\frac{k}{m})^2e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$, if I didn't make any errors.

Comment: Easier is to use reduction of order by the change $z = y'.$

Answer (score 1):

When the inhomogeneous part of a linear ODE is constant, there are far easier methods to get the particular solution. You just have to find a solution to the equation with only the lowest order term, in this case

$$\frac{k}{m}\dot y=-gj.~~(*)$$

The reason is that any $y$ solving this equation will yield $0$ when substituted into the higher order terms, because the lowest order term already makes it a constant, and any higher order derivatives make it 0. Here for instance, $\ddot y=\partial_t\left(-\frac{mg}{k}j\right)=0$, so it also solves the original, higher order equation.

Now finding a particular solution to $(*)$ is easy:

$$y_p(t)=-\frac{gmt}{k}j.$$

In case this is, in fact, about a free falling object: This solution corresponds to the limiting case where friction and gravitation are in equilibrium, yielding a constant velocity of $-\frac{gm}{k}j$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you solving for a falling object ?
Its easier to multiply both sides by $e^{\frac kmt}$  so

$$y''+y'{\frac km}=-g\hat{j}\\ \times e^{\frac kmt} \\
e^{\frac kmt}y''+e^{\frac kmt}y'{\frac km}=-ge^{\frac kmt}\hat{j}\\ (e^{\frac kmt}y')'=-ge^{\frac kmt}\hat{j}$$ no apply integral both sides
$$\int =\int \\e^{\frac kmt}y'=-g\frac {1}{\frac km}e^{\frac kmt}\hat{j}+c\hat{j} $$ now multiply by $e^{-\frac kmt}$ so
$$y'=-g\frac {1}{\frac km}\hat{j}+ce^{-\frac kmt}\hat{j}$$ so
$$y=-g\frac {1}{\frac km}t\hat{j}+c\frac {-1}{\frac km}e^{-\frac kmt}\hat{j}+c_2\hat{j}$$